# jQuery grabbing value of a dynamic data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Inside of a jQuery click event listener I have some code like this:

```
function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  var reportbox = $(this).closest('.activityItem');
  var id = reportbox.data('questionId');
  ...
}
```

This works fine for `data-question-id` attributes, but I'm generalizing the function now and I need to grab the value from any of the following:

```
data-question-id
data-answer-id
data-comment-id
data-user-id
data-company-id
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, why can you not use the `data()` method for those too?

Comment: Use a partial match on the end `-id`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just need a one-liner that can grab the value from any of those regardless. The `.activityItem` element has exclusively one of these but I won't know which one before-hand.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. You would need to retrieve all of those data attributes and then perform some logic to check those which have values and proceed from there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `var id = reportbox.data(Object.keys(reportbox.data())[0]);` Here's my one-liner. Just took a little time to think of it.

Comment: But that will just arbitrarily get the first data attribute on the element, in no guaranteed order - it may not be any of those you've listed. Although, if that works for you then all the better :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I _did_ say that the element would have exclusively only one of these, so this does work for my use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought of what I was looking for. I guess my question confused you, but here's what I wanted:

```js
$('#test').children().each(function () {
  var reportbox = $(this);

  var id = reportbox.data(Object.keys(reportbox.data())[0]);
  
  reportbox.text(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div data-question-id="1"></div>
  <div data-answer-id="2"></div>
  <div data-comment-id="3"></div>
  <div data-user-id="4"></div>
  <div data-company-id="5"></div>
</div>
```

The line of focus being:

```
var id = reportbox.data(Object.keys(reportbox.data())[0]);
```

### Edit

Alternatively thanks to [@Brian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089453/jquery-grabbing-value-of-a-dynamic-data-attribute#comment57902067_35089846) I can rewrite this to:

```
var id = this.dataset(Object.keys(this.dataset)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know only one of those attributes will be present and you want to retrieve that single value you can use this:

```
var element = $(el);
var dataAttrs = ['question-id', 'answer-id', 'comment-id', 'user-id', 'company-id'];
var data = getUnknownAttr(element, dataAttrs);


function getUnknownAttr(element, potentialAttrs) {      
    var $element = element instanceof $ ? element : $(element);
    var result = null;

    potentialAttrs.forEach(function (attr) {
        var temp = $element.data(attr);
        if (typeof temp !== 'undefined') {
            result = temp;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I like this but I actually just came up with a much simpler way.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts please post it! I've got a couple use cases for it. I actually just came up with what I wrote without even implementing it but I was about to. EDIT: I just saw you posted it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

As [Brian points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089453/jquery-grabbing-value-of-a-dynamic-data-attribute/35089846?noredirect=1#comment57902067_35089846), you could access the [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to retrieve all the element's `data-*` attributes:

```
$('.activityItem').each(function () {
  var dataAttributes = this.dataset;

  Object.keys(dataAttributes).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key, dataAttributes[key]); // key, value
  });
});
```

Since you only want the first data attribute, you could simply use:

```
var dataAttributes = this.dataset;
var id = dataAttributes[Object.keys(dataAttributes)[0]];
```

---

It's important to note that the `dataset` property returns the attribute names in camel case without the `data` prefix. In other words, `data-question-id` would be `questionId`.

If you want to retrieve all of an element's attributes, access the `attributes` property and check which attributes start with `data-*` and end with `-id`. It's definitely more verbose, but it may work better in other scenarios.

```
$('.activityItem').each(function () {
  var attributes = this.attributes;

  Object.keys(attributes).forEach(function (key) {
    var attribute = attributes[key];

    if (/^data-.*-id$/.test(attribute.name)) {
      console.log(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Having a regex inside a for-loop isn't exactly the "simple" solution I was looking for, but I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're right--1+ to your answer. I was under the impression that it had to end with `*-id`.

Comment: Your impression was correct, but see my comment to Rory.

Comment: Using `this.dataset` would be more targeted for this use case. The `attributes` object contains all of the elements attributes, not just data-* attributes. Your regex takes care of the others but you could eliminate it completely using `dataset` if (like in this case) you knew there was only one data-* attribute.